# Javascript not working on my Ruby on Rails 7 app

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I'm building a simple blog following this  --> [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCEzxY9BbiU), around minute 53:15 of the video, when it's time to add javascript code for a form to hide and content to show on click, I cannot get the script to work. I am not getting any errors but nothing happens when clicking the form. Since I am using rails 7, I no longer have webpacker, so I figured I would put the script inside the view page with the HTML code and give it a try.

I would like for this content area: [image] to switch into this form -> [image] and for the content above to be hidden when the editing form is open.

Please find below my code for the html.erb page I'm trying to get this to work on:

```html
<style>
    #element_content:hover {
        background-color: #E7E7E7;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= link_to "Back to card", cards_path, class: 'btn btn-secondary mb-3' %>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body"></div>
            <h4 class="card-title m-3">Editing Card</h4>
            <%= render "form", card: @card %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <%= form_with(model: [@card, @paragraph],) do |form| %>
            <%= form.hidden_field :element_type, value: 'paragraph' %>
            <%= form.submit "New Element", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <script>
                    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
                        document.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-content')
                            if (!element) return;

                            element.classList.add('d-none')
                            element.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none')
                        })

                        document.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            if (!event.target.matches('.cancel')) return;

                            let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-form')

                            element.classList.add('d-none')
                            element.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none')
                        })
                    })
                    </script>
            <div class="card-body pt-5">
                <% @card.elements.each do |element| %>
                <% if element.persisted? %>
                <div class="mb-3 p-3 paragraph">
                    <div class="paragraph-content mb-3">
                      <% if element.content.present? %>
                        <%= element.content %>
                      <% else %>
                      New Element will display here.
                      <%  end %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="paragraph-form">
                        <%= form_with(model: [@card, element]) do |form| %>
                        <%= form.rich_text_area :content %>
                        <div class="mt-3">
                            <%= form.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                            <a href="#" class="'cancel btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Below is the actual HTML generated (copied from Chrome's inspector mode)

```html
<html><head><style type="text/css" data-tag-name="trix-editor">trix-editor {
  display: block;
}

trix-editor:empty:not(:focus)::before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  color: graytext;
  cursor: text;
  pointer-events: none;
}

trix-editor a[contenteditable=false] {
  cursor: text;
}

trix-editor img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

trix-editor [data-trix-attachment] figcaption textarea {
  resize: none;
}

trix-editor [data-trix-attachment] figcaption textarea.trix-autoresize-clone {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  max-height: 0px;
}

trix-editor [data-trix-attachment] figcaption[data-trix-placeholder]:empty::before {
  content: attr(data-trix-placeholder);
  color: graytext;
}

trix-editor [data-trix-cursor-target] {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}

trix-editor [data-trix-cursor-target=left] {
  vertical-align: top !important;
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}

trix-editor [data-trix-cursor-target=right] {
  vertical-align: bottom !important;
  margin-right: -1px !important;
}</style><style type="text/css" data-tag-name="trix-toolbar">trix-toolbar {
  display: block;
}

trix-toolbar {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

trix-toolbar [data-trix-dialog] {
  display: none;
}

trix-toolbar [data-trix-dialog][data-trix-active] {
  display: block;
}

trix-toolbar [data-trix-dialog] [data-trix-validate]:invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}</style>
    <title>Knowledgebase</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="oRMykwAKSg6xWWo3LJHmsB1pkPlfYvP4PZN72gBJK2qH4gb2MkylWPcxc6KOni95V8bIxqhAR0dqVgiB2idfEw">
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-904c933b80333e5306f46a2a4a560084b9579e45ffa2564bd024d45caa6b79c5.css" data-turbo-track="reload">
    <script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-53c449d104ca7e92fd7c92a99d5a225fddc3a41a930a27c9621c56294fa3f06f.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-e5023178542f05fc063cd1dc5865457259cc01f3fba76a28454060d33de6f429.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-b8a9738499c7a8362910cd545375417370d72a9776fb4e766df7671484e2beb7.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js",
    "trix": "/assets/trix-1563ff9c10f74e143b3ded40a8458497eaf2f87a648a5cbbfebdb7dec3447a5e.js",
    "@rails/actiontext": "/assets/actiontext-28c61f5197c204db043317a8f8826a87ab31495b741f854d307ca36122deefce.js",
    "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index-1569d47a5473ce34c056f906b4dbc6541274c7f5a61e00a1c1978b90009761e0.js"
  }
}</script>
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/application-53c449d104ca7e92fd7c92a99d5a225fddc3a41a930a27c9621c56294fa3f06f.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/turbo.min-e5023178542f05fc063cd1dc5865457259cc01f3fba76a28454060d33de6f429.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus.min-b8a9738499c7a8362910cd545375417370d72a9776fb4e766df7671484e2beb7.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js">
<script src="/assets/es-module-shims.min-d89e73202ec09dede55fb74115af9c5f9f2bb965433de1c2446e1faa6dac2470.js" async="async" data-turbo-track="reload"></script>
<script type="module">import "application"</script>
  </head>

  <body class="bg-light">
    <div class="container">
    <p class="notice"></p>
    <p class="alert"></p>
    <style>
    #element_content:hover {
        background-color: #E7E7E7;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" href="/cards">Back to card</a>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body"></div>
            <h4 class="card-title m-3">Editing Card</h4>
            <form action="/cards/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="1WnwBmNUcDWLZHN-9SWYtAJlnShGLjDOjLDCy4nHl43bbUvicGTNDQDSCpT0UTgahWR_p8RGY8fQtHro3i3NPw" autocomplete="off">

  <div class="form-group m-3">
    <label for="card_title">Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Card Test" name="card[title]" id="card_title">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group m-3">
    <label for="card_description">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="card[description]" id="card_description">Testing this card</textarea>
  </div>

    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Card" class="btn btn-primary m-3" data-disable-with="Update Card">
  </div>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <form action="/cards/1/elements" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="TmrgVfIbb23NOtQWVNw_SvsV7DuPwJCMBpnRMfAo4vRUHSjIeHRSHPHpZJIluTAvbwImLcihRGIi3ewb7xMGeQ" autocomplete="off">
            <input value="paragraph" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="element[element_type]" id="element_element_type">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="New Element" class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="New Element">
</form>        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <script>
                    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
                        document.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-content')
                            if (!element) return;

                            element.classList.add('d-none')
                            element.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none')
                        })

                        document.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            if (!event.target.matches('.cancel')) return;

                            let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-form')

                            element.classList.add('d-none')
                            element.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none')
                        })
                    })
                    </script>
            <div class="card-body pt-5">
                <div class="mb-3 p-3 paragraph">
                    <div class="paragraph-content mb-3">
                      New Element will display here.
                    </div>
                    <div class="paragraph-form d-none">
                        <form action="/cards/1/elements/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="bGTr4lAuCbfiblGvUmfGioQC9wwckPXUFYuEHr4PgvZh_oTaoKMqIrZOT6vqZ1CFKtD16pyJ7ANvBGnOvA7LDg" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="hidden" name="element[content]" id="element_content_trix_input_element_1" autocomplete="off"><trix-toolbar id="trix-toolbar-1"><div class="trix-button-row">
  <span class="trix-button-group trix-button-group--text-tools" data-trix-button-group="text-tools">
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-bold" data-trix-attribute="bold" data-trix-key="b" title="Bold" tabindex="-1">Bold</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-italic" data-trix-attribute="italic" data-trix-key="i" title="Italic" tabindex="-1">Italic</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-strike" data-trix-attribute="strike" title="Strikethrough" tabindex="-1">Strikethrough</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-link" data-trix-attribute="href" data-trix-action="link" data-trix-key="k" title="Link" tabindex="-1">Link</button>
  </span>

  <span class="trix-button-group trix-button-group--block-tools" data-trix-button-group="block-tools">
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-heading-1" data-trix-attribute="heading1" title="Heading" tabindex="-1">Heading</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-quote" data-trix-attribute="quote" title="Quote" tabindex="-1">Quote</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-code" data-trix-attribute="code" title="Code" tabindex="-1">Code</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-bullet-list" data-trix-attribute="bullet" title="Bullets" tabindex="-1">Bullets</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-number-list" data-trix-attribute="number" title="Numbers" tabindex="-1">Numbers</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-decrease-nesting-level" data-trix-action="decreaseNestingLevel" title="Decrease Level" tabindex="-1">Decrease Level</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-increase-nesting-level" data-trix-action="increaseNestingLevel" title="Increase Level" tabindex="-1">Increase Level</button>
  </span>

  <span class="trix-button-group trix-button-group--file-tools" data-trix-button-group="file-tools">
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-attach" data-trix-action="attachFiles" title="Attach Files" tabindex="-1">Attach Files</button>
  </span>

  <span class="trix-button-group-spacer"></span>

  <span class="trix-button-group trix-button-group--history-tools" data-trix-button-group="history-tools">
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-undo" data-trix-action="undo" data-trix-key="z" title="Undo" tabindex="-1">Undo</button>
    <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-redo" data-trix-action="redo" data-trix-key="shift+z" title="Redo" tabindex="-1">Redo</button>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="trix-dialogs" data-trix-dialogs="">
  <div class="trix-dialog trix-dialog--link" data-trix-dialog="href" data-trix-dialog-attribute="href">
    <div class="trix-dialog__link-fields">
      <input type="url" name="href" class="trix-input trix-input--dialog" placeholder="Enter a URL…" aria-label="URL" required="" data-trix-input="" disabled="disabled">
      <div class="trix-button-group">
        <input type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--dialog" value="Link" data-trix-method="setAttribute">
        <input type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--dialog" value="Unlink" data-trix-method="removeAttribute">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></trix-toolbar><trix-editor id="element_content" input="element_content_trix_input_element_1" class="trix-content" data-direct-upload-url="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" data-blob-url-template="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/:signed_id/:filename" contenteditable="" role="textbox" trix-id="1" toolbar="trix-toolbar-1"></trix-editor>
                        <div class="mt-3">
                            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Save">
                            <a href="#" class="'cancel btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
</form>                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    
  

</body></html>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you give us the actual generated HTML?

Comment: Hello, @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree, thank you for your comment, I've updated the question and added the snippet of the HTML generated from the inspector mode in Chrome.

Comment: What CSS is associated with `d-none`? Is this hiding or showing things based upon `display: none;` maybe?

Comment: Yes, it is associated with display: none; I tried changing the name of the class because d-none is a bootstrap class sp it would hide the elements even without the CSS. After renaming the class and adding the CSS display: none; to it, I tried running the script again but I still got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1. Don't nest your script tag inside a body element

I would move your `<script>` tag into the `<head>` tag or to the bottom of the page, nesting it inside a div is a bit strange.

##### 2. Is the JS even loading?

Try adding an alert or two:

```html
<script>
alert("I loaded!");
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    ...
})
alert("I finished!");
</script>
```

##### 3. In Javascript, semicolons matter.

Every line should end with a semicolon:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-content')
        if (!element) return;

        element.classList.add('d-none');
        element.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none');
    })

    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!event.target.matches('.cancel')) return;

        let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-form');

        element.classList.add('d-none');
        element.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none');
    })
})
```

##### 4. Make your function triggers more specific.

You are adding an event listener for *every* click anywhere in the document, which is overkill. I would try being more specific:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph').addEventListener('click', () => {
        let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-content')
        if (!element) return;

        element.classList.add('d-none');
        element.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none');
    })

    document.getElementsByClassName('cancel').addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!event.target.matches('.cancel')) return;

        let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-form');

        element.classList.add('d-none');
        element.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none');
    })
})
```

##### 5. Focus on what *should* be happening:

In your first click listener, you are saying:

- Find the closest element with the class 'paragraph-content'
- If nothing is found, return
- Add the class 'd-none' to the element
- Remove the class 'd-none' from the next sibling element

So, what *should* adding 'd-none' to the class do? I'm not seeing any any CSS or JS that would change anything in your HTML based upon an element having the 'd-none' class.

I'm guessing you instead want to hide or show the 'content' or the 'form'. You have 2 options to do this:

- Use CSS to hide everything with the 'd-none' class

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

- Make your Javascript more explicit on what you want to happen:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-content');
        if (!element) return;

        // element.classList.add('d-none');
        element.style.display = 'none';
        // element.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none');
        element.nextElementSibling.display = 'inline';
    })

    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!event.target.matches('.cancel')) return;

        let element = event.target.closest('.paragraph-form');

        // element.classList.add('d-none')
        element.style.display = 'none';
        // element.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none');
        element.previousElementSibling.display = 'inline';
    })
})
```

Hopefully this gives you some ideas to play with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. However, the improvements you made for my code did not get it to work, the script is running because I get the alerts you suggested I added, but it still won't do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Since the alerts work, it's time to start debugging! Use [Chrome Devtools' breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/) to interrupt your code so you can test things in the Devtools console. Good luck!

Comment: Solved it while debugging using the breakpoints, found out only the event listener document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => { } was running, code works after removing it. Also I had a syntax mistake in my html, in line <a href="#" class="'cancel btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a> I have an extra single quote before "cancel", after removing it, the button hides the paragraph form now. Thanks for the help.